# How to change characters into NA?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a census dataset with some missing variables indicated with a `?`, 
When checking for incomplete cases in R it says there are none because R takes the `?` as a valid character.  Is there any way to change all the `?` to `NA`s? I would like to run multiple imputation using the mice package to fill in the missing data after.

Comment: See [the documentation page on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/3388/handling-missing-values/11656/basic-usage#t=201607251849114029215)

Comment: Define the na.strings when you import the data.

Comment: See [specifically here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/3388/handling-missing-values/11657/reading-data-with-na-values#t=201607251914346206181).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating data frame `df`

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("?",1,2),B=c(2,3,"?"))
df
#   A B
# 1 ? 2
# 2 1 3
# 3 2 ?
```

I. Using `replace()` function

```
replace(df,df == "?",NA)
#      A    B
# 1 <NA>    2
# 2    1    3
# 3    2 <NA>
```

II. While importing a file with `?`

```
 data <- read.table("xyz.csv",sep=",",header=T,na.strings=c("?",NA))
 data
 # A  B
 # 1  1 NA
 # 2  2  3
 # 3  3  4
 # 4 NA NA
 # 5 NA NA
 # 6  4  5
```

Answer (score 4):

Data frames. You may need to fiddle with the quotation marks. I have not tested this.

```
df[df == "?"] <- NA
```